# PHP echo last Array values

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying few hours repair my code but its always fail.
I have array in file:

```
$liquidyLista7 = array(
    'Arbuz' => array(
        'Wyraźny arbuz, soczysty arbuz, naprawde chyba najlepszy z oferty',
        'Delikatny arbuz.',
        'odświeżajacy arbuz',
        'Bardzo delikatny, mniej wyrażny arbuz'
    ),
    // and much more...
```

... i want to echo all values from each arrays but my "bad epic" code not work :/

```
function pokazOpisyVolish($liquidyLista7)
    {
    $i = 0;
    $select = '<div id="volishPage'.$i.'" class="tab-pane fade"><ul class="comment-list">';
    foreach($liquidyLista7 as $key => $record) {
    $i++;
    if (is_array($record)) {
    $select .= '<li><p class="desc">'.$key.'</p>';
        $select .= pokazOpisyVolish($record);
        $select .= '</li>';
    } else {
    $select .= '<li><p class="desc">'.$record.'</p></li>';
    }
    }
    $select .= '</ul></div>';
    return $select;
    echo pokazOpisyVolish($liquidyLista7);
```

Pls visit my [test website](http://katalogliquidow.mrqzi.webd.pl/) and check how it works in "Mr Jack" (simple HTML - not PHP) but in "Volish" is my PHP code... :(

Comment: To correctly format code just indent four spaces or use the `{}` button.

Comment: `$select .= pokazOpisyVolish($record);` what you are trying to do in this line, as you are using function, if this function does not loop, it wont work, as before this you are saying is array, so i am assuming it has to be array,

Comment: i did not even realize, you are calling the same function inside the function, ?? this wont, just after checking if array add another loop

Comment: Pls check this screen becouse my english is not good enought to tell what i rly wanna do - simple function i think :) http://i65.tinypic.com/oa4zkh.jpg

Comment: check my answer again i edited the code, and run that code in different file

Answer (score 0):

> may be you are looking for some thing like this. the link you gave
>   uses plugin and css to display the result onto the webpage, 
>       i can show you how to do it, but after that you have use your own css to display the result, i am thinking you might have add some div
>   name 
>       just run this code in separate file, and you are good, understand what's happening and than add the div

```
    <?php
$liquidyLista7 = array(
    'Arbuz' => array(
        'Wyraźny arbuz, soczysty arbuz, naprawde chyba najlepszy z oferty',
        'Delikatny arbuz.',
        'odświeżajacy arbuz',
        'Bardzo delikatny, mniej wyrażny arbuz'
    ),

    'newArtist' => array(
        'Wyraźny arbuz, soczysty arbuz, naprawde chyba najlepszy z oferty',
        'Delikatny arbuz.',
        'odświeżajacy arbuz',
        'Bardzo delikatny, mniej wyrażny arbuz'
    )
    );
//get the link from url
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    foreach ($liquidyLista7 as $key => $record) {
        //ad artist name to the current url
        echo "<a href=$actual_link?artistName=$key>$key</a><br>";
        if(isset($_GET['artistName'])){
            if(is_array($record)){
                echo "<ul>";
                foreach($liquidyLista7[$key] as $value)
                    if($_GET['artistName']==$key)
                    echo "<li>$value</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: im pasted it into the file and still its not this :(
http://katalogliquidow.mrqzi.webd.pl/user2860957.php

Comment: @TomaszKużaj the reason it failed, cause you are using some body else platfrom, you need to get the url, and than ad the value to url, pay extra attention to the comment, in the code, added them at two places in my edited answer, it should work